# How to raise PropertyChanged for a different Model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have the following problem: My WPF Application uses a DataGrid to display a list of Tasks. These Tasks are stored in a SQL Database and we use Entity Framework. The shortened Model for the Task is at the end of this question for better readability. The Task Model has a Category object assigned. All categories are stored in the Database and the Category Model can also be seen at the end of this question.

The Category is displayed as a ComboBox in the DataGrid so you can choose:

```
<Window.Resources>    
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="categoryViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Models:Category}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="taskViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Models:Task}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource taskViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" EnableRowVirtualization="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        [DataGridTemplateColumn => DataGrid.CellTemplate => DataTemplate and then:]
        <ComboBox x:Name="categoryValues" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource},
                    Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Category,
                    Mode=TwoWay,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewSources are set in Code, e.g.:

```
await db.Categories.LoadAsync();
categoryViewSource.Source = db.Categories.Local;
```

This works fine. However, when I edit a Category (It is allowed to edit the Category Name), the problems start. The ItemsSource gets Updated accordingly (So in the Dropdown Menu, the value is displayed with the new Name). However, the Binding for SelectedItem doesn't get updated. That means that all ComboBoxes that have the Category that's been edited already selected still show the old value.

I found out that if I do this when changing the value:

```
public void ChangeCategoryName(string name, Category c) 
{
    c.Name = name;
    foreach (var task in c.Tasks) 
    {
        task.Category = null;
        task.Category = c;
    }
}
```

Then the value is updated in the SelectedItem of the ComboBox instantly. My *guess* is that PropertyChanged doesn't get called for `Task` when I change a value in `Category`. I tried forcing the Event like this:

```
public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    // Force Tasks to update
    this.Tasks?.ForEach(t =>
    {
        t.OnPropertyChanged("Category");
    });
}
```

That didn't work. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Here is the code for my Models.

```
namespace Application.Models 
{
    public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Key]
        public int TaskId { get; set; }

        [...]

        // Category is defined in anothre table
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        // The Category object will automatically be loaded if access is needed
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        // PropertyChanged Event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // List of Task objects that are associated to this Category object
        public virtual List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        // PorpertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I identified the source of the problem. First of all, I added `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` like suggested by Ed in the comments. It didn't help. After minimizing a exemplary application until I found the source, the Style I appliy to the ComboBox seems to be the root of the problem. The style is designed to add a 'remove' and an 'edit' button to the ComboBox Items when in DropDown, but show a simple TextBox when not selecting an Item. See yourself:

```
<!--Templates for different Item Styles in ComboBoxes-->
<!--This template is a simple TextBox-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleComboBoxItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
<!--This template contains a remove button and is only shown in the DropDown Menu-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExtendedComboBoxItem" >
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxRemoveButton}"
                x:Name="EditItemFromComboBoxButton" Click="EditItemFromComboBoxButton_Click"
                Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RemoveXFromNullValuesConverter}}">
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Pencil" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Width="8"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxRemoveButton}"
                x:Name="RemoveItemFromComboBoxButton" Click="RemoveItemFromComboBoxButton_Click"
                Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RemoveXFromNullValuesConverter}}">
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Close" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Width="8"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
<!--Style the ComboBox Items so they can align the Remov "X" button to the right--> 
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}" x:Key="RemovableComboboxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
<!--This is the DateTemplate for the ComboBox ItemTemplate-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="RemovableComboBoxItemTemplate">
    <Control x:Name="RemoveableItemsComboBoxControl" Focusable="False" Template="{StaticResource ExtendedComboBoxItem}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="RemoveableItemsComboBoxControl" Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SimpleComboBoxItem}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
<!--ComboBox Style for ComboBoxes with a X for removing the item-->
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" x:Key="RemoveItemComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource RemovableComboboxItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RemovableComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I’m unsure what value you are actually changing, and what effects that’s supposed to have, and how your entities are in relation to another. Can you try to clarify your question? Maybe show at least a screenshot, so it’s clear what controls are there bound to what if you don’t want to show the full XAML. Also, since `this.Tasks` appears to be a collection, you might be interested in a [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) if you want to track changes properly.

Comment: *"My guess is that PropertyChanged doesn't get called for Task when I  change a value in Category."* -- Right! You do nothing that could possibly cause that to happen, so it doesn't happen. If `Category` needs to notify the UI when its properties change, `Category` must raise `PropertyChanged` *on every single property without any exceptions*, and its `Tasks` must be `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: As a rule, `OnPropertyChanged` should be protected. As a rule, no viewmodel should ever raise `PropertyChanged` for a different viewmodel (these are viewmodels, not models). If you're trying to do that, go back and identify the mistaken design decision that created the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @poke I will edit the question in a moment. I thought the XAML was sufficient, I didn't want to blow it up. Basically, I want to change the name of a Category object and achieve that this raises a PropertyChanged Event in all the Task objects that have this category object.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok thanks. Category raises PropertyChanged for every property, I just shortened the Code for better readability.
And yes, I just made it public for test purposes. I was testing if I was able to raise PropertyChanged from a different Model. It didn't work, as described in the question. My question is how do I get a `Task` to raise PropertyChanged when it's `Category` raises PropertyChanged? 

And my Models are Models, right? I describe how the Database is structured, not how my View is.

Comment: *"My question is how do I get a Task to raise PropertyChanged when it's Category raises PropertyChanged?"* -- what requirement are you trying to satisfy by doing that very strange thing? I know *what* you are trying to do; can you explain what problem you were facing when you came up with the idea?

Comment: A viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged. A model doesn't. You can have viewmodels that reflect your DB structure. Nothing wrong with that at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question text is not clear enough. I'm not a native English speaker and sometimes have trouble finding the right words.

I the ComboBox that is displayed in the XAML snippet of the question. It shows the `Category` that's associated to the `Task`. You can edit any category you want (i.e., change its name). When you do that, the ItemsSource (i.e. the DropDown List) is updated with the new `Category.Name`. However, values already being displayed as SelectedItem are not updated (Maybe because the DataContext is a Task?).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ah, thanks for the explanation. That's good to know.
Anyways, to continue my previous comment. I found out that raising PropertyChanged on the Task would update the SelectedItem. That's why I want to do that.

Comment: Try adding `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` to the `ComboBox`. You're relying on the ComboBox calling `Category.ToString()` to get the categories' names, but that leaves it no way of knowing when the names change. The ComboBox has no idea what's inside `Category.ToString()`, so it has no way of knowing when it needs to call `Category.ToString()` again for an updated value. If you explicitly tell it that the `Name` is the property it needs to use, it will update in response to the `Category`'s own `PropertyChanged` event when `Category.Name` is changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had no effect

Comment: So your SelectedItem is `Application.Models.Category`, and you change the `Name` property of *that exact instance* of `Application.Models.Category`. You change the name of the selected category by assigning to its `Name` property, or via a control bound to its `Name` property -- such that the setter is confirmed to be called, and it raises `PropertyChanged` when its `Name` changes. And the only source of `Category` instances is EF: You're not creating any new `Category` anywhere in your own code. Is that all correct? I mean, *all* -- that was a long list of very specific questions.

Comment: That is correct. If I debug, the SelectedItem of the ComboBox even shows the **new** value in the Debugger. But it isn't updated unless I do the stupid trick of unassigning and reassigning the `Category` to the `Task`.

Comment: So it's the same actual object instance in SelectedItem, and you've positively confirmed that to be the case -- it's not just an assumption or an inference or a "trust me". Yet you change its Name, and the Name doesn't update in the ComboBox with `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`. If `Category.Name` correctly raises `PropertyChanged`, that's fairly remarkable. I'd have to see complete code to reproduce that behavior. There are a lot of "ifs" here, a lot of places where I'm taking your word on what your code does.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I double checked it multiple times now. But it is. 

I added my own Event Handler to the PropertyChanged Event and it gets called.

Comment: Something's wrong in code I haven't seen.

Comment: "If I debug, the SelectedItem of the ComboBox even shows the new value in the Debugger" -- New value of what? new value of Category.Name, or new value of Category?

Comment: All this talking is a waste of time; I need code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'll see what Code I can show tomorrow,is that OK? I'll have to double-check.

Comment: Great, shoot me a line when you have it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well, I solved the issue now. Partly thanks to you. I started revising all my code to build a working minimal sample. I'm very thankful for your time and niceness. My issue probably was extremely stupid and I apologize. I'm still new to this

Comment: @LeoReentry Every time I go to ask a question here, I end up resolving the issue in the course of creating an example and anticipating all the issues annoying guys like me will raise. It's a great way to solve problems! Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Remember: When using your own Templates, always make sure you update your changes properly. In my case the Binding in my ComboBoxItem relied on the DataContext:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleComboBoxItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So, in order to subscribe to the PropertyChanged Trigger, I added the Binding Path explicitly:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleComboBoxItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I feel stupid, but I started working with WPF 4 weeks ago, never ever used it before and suddenly I'm a WPF programmer. Please excuse my noobishness.

**EDIT**

Removed some unnecessary Binding instructions. Thanks to Ed!

Comment: All you need there btw is `{Binding Name}` -- all the UpdateSourceTrigger etc flags are no-ops in this particular case.